# Streaming in JPA repository causing crashing

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need to loop through some larger dataset, thats why I am returning `Stream` from the repository call in this way:

```
    @QueryHints(value = {
            @QueryHint(name = HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "500"),
            @QueryHint(name = HINT_CACHEABLE, value = "false"),
            @QueryHint(name = READ_ONLY, value = "true")
    })
    @Query("from StoreEntity")
    Stream<StoreEntity> getAll();
```

I am also using `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` in the service class. However, I am getting `OutOfMemoryException` when processing just 30k entities. I dont create any lists, even if I do just read-only operations on the `StoreEntity` I am getting OOM. Are all entities within transaction anyhow cached by JPA/Hibernate ? This is for me only meaningful reason why it does not free the memory. How would you solve this please?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: Yes, honestly dont remember about the solution. Maybe somewhere i created lists unintentionally.